# How to auto-translate a section using google translate tools?

Tags: javascript, html, click, href, google-translate

This is more like a auto-click link problem. But my problem is this link is generate by google's script.
http://translate.google.com/translate_tools

If you choose "translate a section" , there will be a link generate inside the `goog-trans-control` class

---

Original script:

```
<div class="goog-trans-section">
<div class="goog-trans-control">    
</div>

Original Text here.

</div>
```

Script code after execute (Check Component):

```
<div class="goog-trans-section">
<div class="goog-trans-control">
    <div class="skiptranslate goog-te-sectional-gadget-link" style="">
        <div id=":1.gadgetLink">
        <a class="goog-te-gadget-link" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="goog-te-sectional-gadget-link-text">Translate</span>
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


Original Text here.

</div>
```

---

How would I **auto-click** (or **execute**) the `Translate` link after this page is **totally loaded**?

For some reason, jsfiddle is not working with my [script](http://jsfiddle.net/Wb7tE/), though I still post this for your convenience.
http://jsfiddle.net/Wb7tE/

Really appreciate for your time and help.

**Edited:**
I tried [Google translate API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/reference.html), but there is a limitation of 5000 words at a time.
My translations include whole html with tables and scripts, so it reach the limit with no exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar problem, and I solved it temporally like this

```
    google_initialized = false;

    function google_auto_translate()
    {
        if(google_initialized)
        {
            $('a.goog-te-gadget-link')[0].click();
        }
        else if(google.translate)
        {
            google_initialized = true;
            setTimeout(google_auto_translate, 500);
        }
        else
            setTimeout(google_auto_translate, 100);
    }
window.onload = google_auto_translate;
```

but on slower connection, in 50 % of time google doesn't load on time, and script already clicks before loading is done. So if anyone know any other way to do this, via some events or something similar please add it here...

P.S. Don't use Google Translation API it's Deprecated and will be removed till the end of this year.